# How to make a button displaying a drop down  menu?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, menu, drop-down-menu

I am new at `iPhone` development using `xcode 3.2.6` and I am wondering how I can create a button in the navigation bar which will display a drop down list containing a list which I will program to do things. How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need a `UINavigationController`, which will give you the `UINavigationbar`. In your `.m` file, you can set a button.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(dropDown:)];
```

then you add a method to handle the touch.

```
- (void) dropDown: (id) sender;
```

## Edit

[KSPopoverView](https://github.com/katokichisoft/KSPopoverView) [TSPopover](https://github.com/takashisite/TSPopover) are some open-source Popovers.

Comment: Thanks in advance
but as i said before im new at this field
can you be more specific please

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a big help to me